# Can I position input inside of a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input

I am trying to position an input within a string in python.

For example, the console will read "I am ___ years old", and the input value completes the sentence. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please update the question to show what you've tried / research so far. Where are you stuck?  Hint: Look up `str.replace` or 'string formatting'.

Comment: Try format strings, e.g. `f"I am {the_input_string} years old"`. Or do you mean that the input should be placed in the string _while the user is typing it_, i.e. having an input prompt that encloses the input?

Comment: I think the authoer meant that input cursor should be put somehow within middle of sentence.

Comment: I suspect the answer isn't as easy as some are making this out to be. I think @dav is asking for the blank space to be filled in as the user types.

Comment: The answer to the question is *yes, there is a way*. If you want more, you should show your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want. If you just want the input to be placed into that string, you can, among others, use the new format strings (or just `str.format`, or the `%` operator):

```
age = input("What is your age? ")
print(f"I am {age} years old")
```

If your string actually has that `___` section and you want to insert the age there, you can first replace that with a proper format symbol and then use `format`:

```
import re
s = re.sub("_+", "{}", "I am ___ years old")
print(s.format(age))
```

If, as some suggested in comments, you might actually want the user to fill in the blank as they type, you can first print the line, then use `\r` and `flush` to go back to the beginning and then ask for the input, overwriting just as much so that the input cursor is on the `___` part.

```
print("I am ___ years old", end="\r", flush=True)
age = input("I am ")
print(age)
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option is what I meant, that solves it.

Comment: @dav Actually I just inserted a new second option. Did you mean that, or the now third option?

Answer (score 1):

One more solution using [console ANSI escape chars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and module [ansicon](https://pypi.org/project/ansicon/) (needs once installing through `python -m pip install ansicon`), besides moving cursor it will also give nice things like coloring, etc. Escape chars thanks to this module will work both in Unix and Windows systems. Unix supports escape chars natively even without this module.

```
# Needs: python -m pip install
import ansicon
ansicon.load()

age = int(input('I am ___ years old' + '\x1b[D' * 13))
print('Your age is:', age)
```

Using escape chars many things can be done, e.g. coloring word `years` in green, using next line of code:

```
age = int(input('I am ___ \x1b[32myears\x1b[m old' + '\x1b[D' * 13))
```

which outputs:

[image: img]

Unix systems need no modules at all, thus code can be just two lines, this code you [can see and try here online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64152921#main.py)

Color table for standard set of colors can be easily printed by next code, these numbers should be placed instead of `32` in code `\x1b[32m` above:

```
for first, last in [(30, 47), (90, 107)]:
    for color in range(first, last + 1):
        print(f'\x1b[{color}m{str(color).rjust(3)}\x1b[m ', end = '')
    print()
```

which outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
words_list= ["I","am","x","years","old"] # sentence having missing value as "x"
val = input("how many years old are you ?") # input the value of "x"
words_list[2] = val # replace the value of "x" at right place
print(' '.join(word for word in words_list)) # get the output with missing owrd at right place as sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = ("how old are you ? : ")
print("you are ",user_input"," this old !")
```